# For this sentence should I use "reflect" or "reflects"

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

Should I use "reflect" or "reflects" for the following sentence?

> The theme of [Book 1] and [Book 2] ultimately **reflects/reflect** how family units are fluid.

Comment: Theme is singular, so the verb should be reflects.

Comment: @Khan: Sounds like an answer, you should post it.

Answer (score 2):

- The **theme** of *[Book 1]* and *[Book 2]* ultimately ***reflects/reflect*** how family units are fluid.

"**Theme**" is singular here and points to both the books so the singular form "**reflects**" is correct. Should there have been two themes each of which would have pointed to a single book you would have to use the plural "**teflect**".